# Possible to selective sync dropbox or other cloud storage from multi-platform command line?

Tags: shell, terminal, dropbox, dropbox-api

Going to be working with a medium sized remote group on a large (but independent) project that will be generating many GB to TB of data.

To keep users from having to store 500GB of data on their personal machines, and to keep everyone in sync, we need a command-line/python utility to control selective syncing of dependencies on **multiple operating systems**: or at *least* **osx** and **linux**.

So example, someone who needs to work on the folder:

- startrek/startrekiii

May require the folders:

- startrek/nimoy/common
- startrek/nimoy/[user]
- startrek/shatner/common
- startrek/shatner/[user]

but not:
startrek/startrekii, startrek/nimoy/[some_other_user], etc

From their command line (or a UI) they would run:

```
sync startrekiii
```

And they'd also receive startrek/nimoy/common, etc

likewise we'll have an unsync command that, as long as those dependent folders are not in use by another sync, will be unsynced and removed from the user's HD.

Of cloud sync/storage solutions, dropbox seems to offer the most granular control over this, allowing you to sync specific folders and subfolders - however from everything I can find this granular control is strictly limited to their UI.

We're completely open to alternative solutions if you have them, we just need something as easily deployable as possible and don't have the budget for Aspera or something to that effect.

Two other important notes:

1. Because of one very central part of our pipeline which pulls files
   from those dependent folders (over which we have limited API
   control), the paths need to be consistent on their respective
   platform. So ~/Dropbox/startrek/nimoy can never be ~/Dropbox/startrek/startrekiii/nimoy
2. Many of the people using this will be artists and otherwise non-technical people, the extent of who's experience using csh or bash is for simple things like changing directories and moving files around.

Has anyone found a way to hack into Dropbox's selective sync, and/or know of a better alternative?

Comment: To confirm, there currently isn't a programmatic interface for Dropbox selective sync, but we'll consider this a feature request for one.

Comment: This would be *incredibly* useful for larger, professional collaborative projects and something that none of the competition seems to have implemented.

It's something many groups within in my industry (film/tv) have been seeking a solution for several years now.

Are there any less sanctioned ways to do this? Our project is getting underway now so unfortunately whatever our final solution is, we don't have long to wait.

Comment: I'm not aware of any unofficial ways to do so (and I couldn't recommend them in any case).